# How to include a variable in mysql connectivity query?

Tags: python, sql, connectivity

```
my_connect = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="xyz", 
      passwd="xyz",
      database="tracking"
    )
    my_conn = my_connect.cursor()

    x = input("enter name")
    query="SELECT * FROM trackingtable WHERE Customer_Name = \"x\"";
    print(query)
    my_conn.execute(query)

    my_conn.close()
```

[Query printed statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvWxW.png)

How do i get the proper query using the input from user? I tried using placeholders but I couldn't get them to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
query = f"SELECT * FROM trackingtable WHERE Customer_Name = {x}"
```

It's an `f-string` in which you can plug in variables via `{}`.

If you need the `"`s inside the query:

```
query = f'SELECT * FROM trackingtable WHERE Customer_Name = "{x}"'
```

Do you need the `;` at the end?

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about the f-string and it's use, the query is working wihtout ; at the end!